# JavaScript sum average highest lowest score

Tags: javascript

```
function getScore() {
    var score = 0;
    var sum = 0;
    while (score != -99) {
        sum = sum + score;
        score = parseInt(prompt("Enter a score or enter -99 when you're done:"," "));
    } 
    document.write("<p>The score total: " + sum + ".</p>");
}
```

for now, when i just click the button, it shows the sum, I want to know if I want to get the average, highest and lowest score for the input, what should I do?

Comment: Please format your code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
function getScore() {
    var average = 0
    var sum = 0;
    var highest = 0;
    var lowest = 0;
    var count = 0
    var score = 0;
    
    
    while (score != -99) {
        score = parseInt(prompt("Enter a score or enter -99 when you're done:", " "));
        if(score == -99)
            break;
        if(count == 0)
            lowest = score;
        count++;
        sum += score;
        average = sum/count;
        if(score > highest)
            highest = score;
        if(score < lowest)
            lowest = score;
        
    }
    
    return {"count": count, "sum": sum, "average": average, "highest": highest, "lowest": lowest};
}
console.log(getScore());
```

Answer (score 0):

Place Numbers in a array and then you can use the everage, min and max functions

Answer (score 0):

You should assess whether the current value is greater or less than the previous

```js
var nmbs = [1, 34, 45, 65, 9],
    min = nmbs[0], 
    max = nmbs[0];

for(i in nmbs){
    //check max&min
    if(nmbs[i] > max){
        max = nmbs[i];
    }
    if(nmbs[i] < min){
        min = nmbs[i];
    }
}

document.querySelector(".result").innerHTML = "Max = "+max+" & Min = "+min;
```

```html
<p class="result"></p>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this.  I replaced your `sum` variable with an array.

```
function getScore() {
    var score = 0;
    var scores = [];
    while (score != -99) {

        score = parseInt(prompt("Enter a score or enter -99 when you're done:"," "));
        if (score != -99) scores.push(score);
    } 
    var sum = 0;
    var minvalue = 0;
    var maxvalue = 0;
    for(var t = 0; t < scores.length; t++) { 
        sum += scores[t];
        if (t === 0) {
            // we default the min/max on the first time through
            minvalue = scores[t];
            maxvalue = scores[t];
        } else {
            // after that we start comparing.
            if (scores[t] < minvalue) { minvalue = scores[t]; }   
            if (scores[t] > maxvalue) { maxvalue = scores[t]; }
        }
    }
    var avg = sum / scores.length;

    document.write("<p>The score total: " + sum + ", average: " + avg + ", max: " + maxvalue + ", min: " + minvalue + "</p>");
}
```

**EDIT BASED ON COMMENT **
I added a `Max` and `Min` value to the function above.  Speaking specifically to your comment, if you use this solution `-99` will never be in the set of `scores`.  If it is, find out where its getting added to the `scores` array and prevent it.

Comment: this one is really helpful, but I wanna ask if I also want to get the min and max, how should I do?

Comment: actually I know how to get the highest and lowest, but if I only this code: if(score > highest)
            highest = score;
        if(score < lowest)
            lowest = score; the lowest is always -99, how can I fix it?

Comment: @StevenHuang can you ask that as a separate question or update the code in question so that it is current.

Comment: @StevenHuang whats going on with this? did it help?